# Values not being displayed in logcat, which are retrieved successfully from the database as a JSON array

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting a JSON array from PHP, which is being displayed in the LogCat below. But the specific values from the JSON array are not being displayed in the LogCat. Like it should display formid and date... which I am trying to display.

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

    int success = 0;
    String message = "";

    Log.d("postexxec pa2welcome", "starting");
    if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing())
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    else if (json != null)
    {
        String formid = "";
        String date = "";
        JSONArray data = null;
        try {
            data = json.getJSONArray("details");
            JSONObject obj = data.getJSONObject(0);
            formid = obj.getString("formID");
            date = obj.getString("event_date");

            **Log.d("formid", formid); // Not displaying
            Log.d("date..",date); // Not displaying**

        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
                        welcome.this,
                        "unsuccessful",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        );
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) toast.getView();
        TextView messageTextView = (TextView) group.getChildAt(0);
        messageTextView.setTextSize(20);
        messageTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

#### LOGCAT

```
07-05 21:20:42.524 22779-23117/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/request pa2welcome: starting

07-05 21:20:42.528 22779-22779/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/preexec: starting

07-05 21:20:42.542 22779-23117/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/JSON Parser: result: {"welcome":"successful","details":[{"formID":"19","event_date":"2016-06-03"}],"success":1,"message":"successful"}

07-05 21:20:42.542 22779-23117/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/JSON result pa2welcome: {"welcome":"successful","details":[{"formID":"19","event_date":"2016-06-03"}],"success":1,"message":"successful"}

07-05 21:20:42.543 22779-23117/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/reqpostasyncwelcome: starting

07-05 21:20:42.561 22779-23117/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/JSON Parser: result: {"success":1}

07-05 21:20:42.561 22779-22825/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

07-05 21:20:42.566 22779-22825/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe19b0560, error=EGL_SUCCESS

07-05 21:20:42.575 22779-22779/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application D/postexxec pa2welcome: starting
```

Comment: `JSONObject obj=data.getJSONObject(0);` -> `[` is a array in JSON not a JSONObject so you need to fix that.

Comment: @Shubhank Can you please tell how can I fix it?

Comment: can you show your full code.. where do you log the result ? `starting
result: {"success":1}`

Comment: @Shubhank It is already shown above . result: {"welcome":"successful","details":[{"formID":"19","event_date":"2016-06-03"}],"success":1,"message":"successful"}

Comment: yes but i want to know if the variable passed in onPostExecute is indeed of correct json or maybe has different content

Comment: @Shubhank Everything else is correct as I am getting the correct result.Its just how to pick form id and date from the JSON array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116608/discussion-between-shubhank-and-somya-arora).